# Setting variable in one view controller for another, and swapping to that view controller

Tags: ios

Ok, so i have an interesting situation here:

I have a calendar View, this view does not have a navigation bar, so i created another View to contain the Calendar and added a navigation bar to that view.

So now i have 2 Views displaying a navigation bar and a calendar.

The navigation bars has a butten that is supposed to present a "Insert" controllers, but before it does that, it has to set a @property from the calendar to the "Insert" view controller.

So to sum it up:

Outer View Controller IBAction -> Inner Calendar Set Property on "Insert" -> Inner Calender Present "Insert".

Here is the code:

ViewControllerCalendarContainer.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewControllerCalendarContainer : UIViewController

- (IBAction)SeguqInsert:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewControllerCalendarContainer.m

```
#import "ViewControllerCalendarContainer.h"
#import "CalendarMonthViewController.h"

...

- (IBAction)SeguqInsert:(id)sender {

     CalendarMonthViewController *controller = [[CalendarMonthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
     [controller SegueInsert];

}
```

CalendarMonthViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *dateSelected; // data to send to Insert View Controller

- (void)SegueInsert; // the present "Insert View Controller Method"
```

CalendarMonthViewController.m

```
#import "CalendarMonthViewController.h"
#import "ViewControllerInsert.h"

- (void)SegueInsert {

    NSDate *dateUserSelected = self.dateSelected;

    ViewControllerInsert *controller = [[ViewControllerInsert alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerInsert" bundle:nil];

    controller.dateSelected = dateUserSelected; // set property in Insert

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil]; // present

}
```

Runtime error on click:

on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

PS: I cannot Segue via Storyboard, since it uses another instance, and the property that is supposed to get set, does not get set.

Comment: Your PS doesn't make sense. There's no reason you can't do this in a storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wain is right. The extra view controller is causing a problem. However, I don't think you will be able to just move the code over. You should keep a pointer to your calendar in your navigation controller and just set the property in SequqInsert. Something like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewControllerCalendarContainer : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) CalendarMonthViewController *calendarViewController;

- (IBAction)SeguqInsert:(id)sender;

@end


#import "ViewControllerCalendarContainer.h"
#import "CalendarMonthViewController.h"

...

- (IBAction)SeguqInsert:(id)sender {

    NSDate *dateUserSelected = self.dateSelected;
    ViewControllerInsert *controller = [[ViewControllerInsert alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerInsert" bundle:nil];
    controller.dateSelected = calendarViewController.dateUserSelected; // set property in Insert
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil]; // present

}
```

If you're worried about keeping a pointer to the calendar, you can always use protocols to acquire the information.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have added a view controller that you don't need. The error is because you never show that view controller and then try to present another view controller from it.

Take the code in `SegueInsert` and move it to `SeguqInsert`. Then delete the `CalendarMonthViewController` (which presumably isn't doing anything else and has no other code).